# Metadata preservation when modifying images with ImageMagic

Tags: images, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I want to resize, convert or resize + convert images in JPEG, PNG and TIFF in each direction: jpg → tiff, tiff → png, etc.

And I want to use `-flatten` as well.

What does ImageMagick do with the metadata?

I can't test right now.

Comment: Depends on the image format and the kind of editing/conversion.

Comment: @Gilles Which formats and which kinds of editing/conversion are affected?

Comment: @Anthon I will convert / edit images (png, jpg, gif, ico) with ImageMagick on a Debian Command Line installation. And i want to know if the original Metadata are saved in the new image, after editing / converting.

Comment: And what kind of edits? For example, if you crop an image, surely you wouldn't expect the image size to be preserved.

Comment: @Gilles As example i want to use `-flatten` so i need to know what happens to the metadata

Comment: @Gilles I've updated my question.

Comment: @Anthon I've updated my question.